# @CreatedDate/@LastModifiedDate set to null when merging entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add auditability to my entities using Spring's `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate`. I am using Hibernate with Spring Boot.

It works for inserts, but i have issues when updating entities by reusing IDs.

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity
class Serie(
    val name: String,
    val url: URL
) {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  var id: Long = 0

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  var createdDate: LocalDateTime? = null

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Column(nullable = false)
  var modifiedDate: LocalDateTime? = null
```

In my code the entities are coming from a disk scan, so when i perform a periodic scan the newly scanned objects (not yet persisted) can be in 3 different states:

1. does not exist anymore, in which case i need to delete the objects in DB
2. does not exist yet, in which case i need to insert the objects in DB
3. already exist in DB, in which case i need to update the object

The case I struggle with is the third one (update), which I handle by finding the ID of the object (using the unique URL field), and setting it on the not-yet-persisted object, then saving (using Spring JPA repository):

```
serieRepository.findByUrl(newSerie.url)?.let { existingSerie ->
          newSerie.id = existingSerie.id
}
serieRepository.save(newSerie)
```

It works fine to update the object for my own fields (`name`, and others I omitted for clarity's sake), however after the update the fields `createdDate` and `modifiedDate` are set to `null`.

I am not sure if reusing IDs like this is a good practice, but it helps to have immutable entities in my code. I suppose I could instead update the object already in DB using setters, but that would force me to change all the fields of my entities from `val` to `var`.

Would you know if it's possible to get those creation and last modification time using this kind of update strategy ?

Comment: Have you tried finding the entities by ID then updating them (the existing ones) instead of saving the objects creating by your hand ?

Comment: That's what i ended doing in, yes, It seems Hibernate manages the entities and not just the IDs, so it doesn't work well in my initial usage.